# Sleep function not working inside for loop using Perl Script

Tags: perl

My code is:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl 
use Time::Piece;
use Time::HiRes;
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
my $i = 1;
my $starttime = localtime->strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M');
open my  $file, '>', 'order.properties' or die $!;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){   
  print $file "Start_time_$i = $starttime\n";
  sleep (120);
}
close $file;
```

In the above code I am creating an `order.properties` file and writing a variable called `Starttime` and assigning date and time in a format of `YYYYMMDDHH24MM` and iterating the variable for 10 time with sleep time 2 mins, but sleep is not working and after adding sleep function to the Script, it's just creating a file not writing anything into it.

For each iteration of for loop I need 2 mins of sleep like:

```
 Start_time_1 = 201812141350
 Start_time_2 = 201812141352
```

The output should be like above.

Comment: Works for me ... ?  (I copy-pasted your code).  Btw, why is there `Time::HiRes`?

Comment: However, `$starttime` doesn't change in the loop and is the same in each iteration.

Comment: Tip: `foreach my $i (1..10) { ... }` is the same as the C-style for loop but much nicer.

Comment: Think about where you set `$starttime` and where your loop is. When do you want `$starttime` to change?

Comment: I'm not sure why you gave this question the title you did. Surely, it's obvious that running your code takes 20 seconds. So the call to `sleep()` is clearly working as expected :-)

Comment: Change `sleep (120)` to `sleep(120)` without space. Perl is forgiving thou.

Comment: @KjetilS. - That change would be completely pointless.

Comment: @DaveCross Maybe not to someone new to Perl.

Comment: @KjetilS. - Not sure what you mean. `sleep(120)` and `sleep (120)` both mean *exactly* the same thing to Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `$starttime` outside of the loop and never change it. Therefore it always has the same value. If you want it to change in the loop, then you need to change it in the loop.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){  
  my $starttime = localtime->strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M'); 
  print $file "Start_time_$i = $starttime\n";
  sleep (120);
}
```

Of course, at that point, you have to wonder if there's any good reason to have the variable at all.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){  
  print $file "Start_time_$i = ", localtime->strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M'), "\n";
  sleep (120);
}
```

And, please make your maintenance programmer's life easier by using a `foreach` loop there.

```
foreach my $i (1 .. 10) {  
  print $file "Start_time_$i = ", localtime->strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M'), "\n";
  sleep (120);
}
```

Comment: After running the Script it is creating the file but not writing into the file (file size is o KB)

Comment: @sravs: If you have a new question, it's probably best to ask it as a new question.